# How to glue two functions continuously

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to construct a family of real functions, $f_1,f_2,\ldots$, on the interval $[0,1]$ with the following properties:

- For every $k$, $f_k$ is strictly increasing.
- For every $k$, $f_k(1)=1$.
- Define $I_k = \int_{0}^{x_0} f_k(y)dy$  (for some constant $x_0$). Then $I_k$ should be as small as possible, i.e, $I_k\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$.
- Define $J_k = \int_{x_0}^{1} f_k(y)dy$. Then $J_k$ should be as large as possible, i.e, $J_k\to(1-x_0)$ as $k\to\infty$.
- For every $k$, $f_k$ has continuous first and second derivatives in $[0,1]$.

Without the last condition, the problem is quite easy. We can "glue" together two functions - a function that is nearly 0 at the left, and a function that is nearly 1 at the right. For example, we can take ([See graph here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2qruhsrn1f)):
$$
f_k(x) = 
\begin{cases}
(1-1/k)({x\over x_0})^{k} & x\in[0,x_0])
\\
{(1-1/k)(1-x) + (x-x_0) \over 1-x_0} & x\in[x_0,1])
\end{cases}
$$
Note that every $f_k$ is continuous with $f_k(x_0)=1-1/k$, but not continuously differentiable.

Is there a way to construct functions $f_k$ with similar properties, but that also have continuous first and second derivatives?

Comment: Maybe $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \arctan \left[ N \tan \pi \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right) \right]$ ? ([see here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ixocxezjyb)) I don't get whether it should be $f$ or $1/f$ though.

Comment: @Adayah the integral for this function does not go to 0 at the left... see the updated question.

Comment: The integral $$\int \limits_0^{\frac{1}{2}} f_N(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$$ definitely goes to $0$ for $f_N(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \arctan \left[ N \tan \pi \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right) \right]$. You can replace $N$ by $N^2$ in the graph drawing tool above to see how it behaves for bigger $N$.

Comment: @Adayah I see! Indeed this looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textbook solution is to use as a *building block* the function $h(x)=\exp(-1/x)$ for $x>0$ and $h(x)=0$ otherwise.  This transitions from $0$ to positive values in a $C^\infty$ way as $x$ passes from negative to positive.  Use it to build $g(x) = h(1/2+x)h(1/2-x)$, a $C^\infty$ function whose graph looks like a blip centered at $0$, vanishing outside of $[-1/2,1/2]$.  Let $G(x) = \int_{-\infty}^xg(t)\,dt$ be the indefinite integral of $g$.  Note that $G(x)/G(1)$ climbs smoothly from $0$ to $1$ on $[-1/2,1/2]$. Finally, let $f_n(x) = G(n(x-1/2))/G(1)$, which climbs smothly from $0$ to $1$ in the range $[0,1]$, with all the action within $1/n$ of $1/2$.

Comment: This function is not optimal. Probably the question was not clear enough. See the clarified question now.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I did not suggest that $g(x)$ answered your question, merely that it could be a piece of an answer to your question. I have now spelled out the detail for how to do this.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I get: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cwmqqe4iav it looks good.